# React event not updating the state

Tags: reactjs

My state [event.target.value]is not updating when programmatically updating it. I have read few solutions but unable to pen down in my code. Here `item.rate` is the value coming dynamicaly after calculation. My onchange event not firing due to which my state setTrip is not updated. Ideally the item.rate value should get assigned to the state.

```
const tripChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setTrip({
        ...trip,
        freight: [event.target.value]
    })
}

<Form.Control type="text"  name="freight"
    onChange={tripChange}      
    value={
            rates
                .filter((item) => {
                    return item.consignorCity === trip.consignorDetails.city
                        && item.consigneeCity === trip.consigneeDetails.city
                        && item.commodity === trip.commodity[0]
                        && item.rateType === trip.vendor[0]
                })
                .map((item) => {
                    return item.rate
                })
            
    }
/>
```

Comment: Consider including a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
and it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: Is it the `[event.target.name]` you are trying to update or the value assigned to that dynamically generated key? I agree that if you could create a minimal reproducible example it will help us help you. Create a runnable code in your post above, follow this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: its the [event.target.name] I want to update with the programmatically updated` item.rate`.  [event.target.name] is nothing but `freight` object inside my state setTrip

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using useRef hooks